# IBM Worklight 5.0.5 - Play custom sound on push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

When I use

```
WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, {
        badge: 1,
        sound: "notification.wav",
        activateButtonLabel: "ClickMe",
        alert: notificationText,
        payload: {
            foo : 'bar'
        }
    });
```

to push a notification in IBM Worklight 5.0.5 on Android, it does not seem to be possible to use the custom sound option. No matter where I put the sound file, Worklight does not find it. According to the client traces, it does not even search for the file. Has anybody ever tried this successfully?

Comment: is your question resolve? Mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

To use a custom notification sound:

1. If the folder does not exist already, add a folder named `raw` under the existing `native\res` folder in `yourProject\apps\yourApp\android\native`
2. Place the sound file in the `raw` folder

When sending a notification it should now play your custom sound file.

You can also place the sound file in a `raw` folder under `yourProject\apps\yourApp\android\nativeResources\res`; this will make sure the file will be copied to your generated Android project upon build, in case you have deleted the `native` folder for whichever reason.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it still does not work. In the resulting Android project I have the raw folder on the same level as asset (i.e. in the root). I tried mp3 and wav. No success. I hear just the normal 'Ping'.

Comment: Did you also make sure to update the sound:value in your WL.Server.notify... function?

Comment: Hi Frank, I am able to use a custom notification sound by what Idan suggested (Putting the sound file under `yourProject\apps\yourApp\android\nativeResources\raw`) and submit the notification with sound option. However, there will not be any default sound if I do not do so.. Notice that you can here the normal 'Ping' sound, may I know which Android device and OS version are you using? Thanks.

Comment: @FrankMielke, I have slightly corrected my answer. The "raw" folder should be placed under the "native\res" folder.

Comment: @FrankMielke, if this answer helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.