# IBM Worklight 5.0.6 - Play custom sound on push notification error

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I've folow this tutorial : [IBM Worklight 5.0.5 - Play custom sound on push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187608/play-custom-sound-on-push-notification-in-ibm-worklight)

but get an error:
[image]

Comment: What is your Worklight version? What is your Android version? Device or Emualator?

Comment: my worklight version is 5.0.6,android version target=android-8, android version on device is 4.0.4

Comment: What is your Android version? Device or Emualator?

Comment: ,android version target=android-8,minSdkVersion="7", android version on device is 4.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you placed the `raw` folder in the wrong location.
It should be INSIDE the `res` folder.

If you don't have a nativeResources folder in your project, just make sure to create a `raw`-named folder in the `native\res` folder and place the sound file there.

Just as FYI:

1. I've imported the Push Notifications project
2. Updated application-descriptor.xml with my GCM ID and Key
3. Edited the adapter's *-impl.js file with:

   > ```
   > WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, {
   >       badge: 1,
   >       sound: "alarma.wav",
   >       activateButtonLabel: "ClickMe",
   >       alert: notificationText,
   >       payload: {
   >           foo : 'bar'
   >       }
   >   });
   > ```
4. Placed alarama.was in the nativeResources's `raw` folder

   [image]
5. Deployed adapter
6. Built and deployed application
7. Launched in device running Android OS v4.0.4
8. Logged-in with user "Idan"
9. Sent the notification text "test" to user "Idan"
10. Received it in device with the horrible alarma sound file I placed in the project

Comment: Great,i've just need put alarma.wav in the nativeResources's raw folder every thing ok,thanks you so much.

Comment: Hello Idan, may i provide any username for getting notification?as you logged in with user "idan". or any other setting req for this?

Comment: The sample app provided by Worklight does not require any specific username/password combination; you may login with any username and a password is not required. When you develop your own application it is encouraged of course to use real authentication. For this, read the training materials about authentication.